# Django dynamically add fields without creating new model instances

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform, formset

I'm attempting to create a form that allows someone to enter multiple phone numbers. I'd like to make it possible to click a button to add an additional field to the form but I am not quite sure how to do that.

I looked at `FormSet`s but I don't want to create a new model instance every time someone adds a new phone number.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One way is, you could consider using an [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) or [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield) for the phone numbers. The latter might be more useful if you want to always be able to easily  reference the numbers e.g

```
{'primary_no': '+123232323'}
```

Then for the frontend you can use a button with Javascript to 'clone' the `input` element (or better create a new one with the same class names) and append it to a phone number wrapper div on `click`. But you'll need to take note to use the same field name like one would for a `checkbox` element e.g

```html
<input type="text" name="phone_number[]" />
```

This would make the values of these fields be sent in an array for `request.POST.getlist('phone_number[]')`, which you can then loop through and validate. I left out the nitty gritty details here but this should give you an idea.